# Football game simulation

Tags: python, game, csv, simulation

I'm working on a text-based football simulation game along the lines of Football Simulator. Below is a subset of my total code, specifically the functions used to create a new player. I also have functions (not shown) to create a new coach, create the teams, create the weekly schedules, etc. I'm hoping to be able to use the feedback I get here to improve those sections as well.

Before anyone suggests storing the data in a database, I started out that way, but ending up opting for dictionaries/lists instead for several reasons, so please try to look past that.

Anyway, here goes. The biggest thing I'm struggling with is having to pass a list (`person_data`) of all the parameters needed by `create_new_player`. I don't feel it's efficient to have to build up a list before calling the function, pass it, then have to deconstruct it inside the function. I know using global variables isn't recommended, so I'm not sure if there are any other options. I have to do similar things (albeit using a list of different parameters) for my other functions. I appreciate all feedback you may have.

EDIT: I made a mistake in my original post, I use player_id_index to keep track of how many players have been created, so that the next time I call `create_new_player` it starts where the previous one left off, even though it's not shown below.

```
# python3
import csv
from random import choice, randint, gauss

def create_names_first_data():
    '''
    create a list of all possible first names using text file as source data
    '''
    first_names = []
    filename_first = 'resources/names_first.txt'
    with open(filename_first, 'r') as file_to_open:
        for line in file_to_open:
            data = line.split()
            new_name = data[0]
            first_names.append(new_name)
    return first_names

def create_names_last_data():
    '''
    create a list of all possible last names using text file as source data
    '''
    last_names = []
    filename_last = 'resources/names_last.txt'
    with open(filename_last, 'r') as file_to_open:
        for line in file_to_open:
            data = line.split()
            new_name = data[0]
            last_names.append(new_name)
    return last_names

def create_states_data():
    '''
    create a list of all possible towns/state with their population 
    using text file as source data
    '''
    states = {}
    filename_states = 'resources/state_populations.csv'
    with open(filename_states, 'r') as file_to_open:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_to_open)
        for i in reader:
            state_name = i['state']
            states[state_name] = {}
            states[state_name]['abbreviation'] = i['abbreviation']
            states[state_name]['population'] = i['population']
            states[state_name]['towns'] = {}

    towns = {}
    filename_towns = 'resources/city_populations_locations.csv'
    with open(filename_towns, 'r') as file_to_open:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_to_open)
        for i in reader:
            town_name = i['city']
            state = i['state']
            towns[town_name] = {}
            towns[town_name]['population'] = i['population']
            towns[town_name]['latitude'] = i['latitude']
            towns[town_name]['longitude'] = i['longitude']

            for j in states:
                if state == states[j]['abbreviation']:
                    states[j]['towns'][town_name] = towns[town_name]
    return states

def get_home_town_state(states_dict):
    '''
    randomly pick a town/state
    '''
    states_list = [_ for _ in states_dict]
    state = choice(states_list)
    towns_dict = states_dict[state]['towns']
    towns_list = [_ for _ in towns_dict]
    town = choice(towns_list)
    return town, state

def generate_gauss_dist(mean, std_dev, minimum, maximum):
    '''
    utility function
    randomly generate a number based on a gauss distribution
    '''
    number = gauss(mean, std_dev)
    while (minimum <= number <= maximum) == False:
        number = gauss(mean, std_dev)
    number = int(round(number))
    return number

def create_new_player(param_list, seed=0, position=None):
    '''
    create a new player

    seed numbers are used to generate better/worse players as necessary

    if a position parameter is passed, that position will be used, otherwise
    it will be chosen based upon certain probabilities, i.e. - don't need
    many Ps/Ks

    player_interest is a dictionary of what the player cares about most when
    deciding which team to play for
    '''
    first_names_list = param_list[0]
    last_names_list = param_list[1]
    states_dict = param_list[2]
    positions_list = param_list[3]

    firstname = choice(first_names_list)
    lastname = choice(last_names_list)
    name = '{0} {1}'.format(firstname, lastname)

    town, state = get_home_town_state(states_dict)

    seeds = {
        0: {'mean': 50, 'min': 1,  'max': 100},
        1: {'mean': 92, 'min': 85, 'max': 99},
        2: {'mean': 82, 'min': 75, 'max': 89},
        3: {'mean': 69, 'min': 59, 'max': 79},
        4: {'mean': 54, 'min': 44, 'max': 64}
    }
    rating_seed = seeds[seed]
    mean = rating_seed['mean']
    std_dev = mean / 3.25
    minimum = rating_seed['min']
    maximum = rating_seed['max']
    rating = generate_gauss_dist(mean, std_dev, minimum, maximum)

    probability_list = [5, 6, 10, 5, 15, 15, 12, 13, 2, 2]
    position_probabilities = []
    for i in zip(positions_list, probability_list):
        position_probabilities.extend([i[0]] * i[1])

    if position is None:
        position = choice(position_probabilities)

    player_interests = {}
    player_interests['money'] = randint(1, 10)
    player_interests['play for a winner'] = randint(1, 10)
    player_interests['team facilities'] = randint(1, 10)
    player_interests['team location'] = randint(1, 10)
    player_interests['coach prestige'] = randint(1, 10)

    new_player = {
        'name': name,
        'position': position,
        'rating': rating,
        'player interests': player_interests,
        'home state': state,
        'home town': town
    }
    return new_player


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    it isn't implemented using __name__==__main__ in the real thing,
    but you get the idea
    '''
    first_names_list = create_names_first_data()
    last_names_list = create_names_last_data()
    states_dict = create_states_data()
    positions_list = [
        'QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'OL', 'DL', 'LB', 'DB', 'P', 'K'
    ]

    person_data = [
        first_names_list,
        last_names_list,
        states_dict,
        positions_list
    ]

    player_id_index = 0
    player_dict = {}

    for _ in range(5000):
        player_id_index += 1
        new_player = create_new_player(person_data)
        player_dict[player_id_index] = new_player
```

Answer (score 3):

You **don't** need to **define and increment the `player_id_index`** variable outside of the for loop:

```
player_id_index = 0
player_dict = {}

for _ in range(5000):
    player_id_index += 1
    new_player = create_new_player(person_data)
    player_dict[player_id_index] = new_player
```

Just do:

```
for player_id_index in range(1, 5000):
    player_dict[player_id_index] = create_new_player(person_data)
```

Or reduce it all to this dict comprehension:

```
player_dict = {id_: create_new_player(id_) for id_ in range(1, 5000)}
```

---

**Unpack the tuple** in the head of this for loop to make it more readable:

```
for i in zip(positions_list, probability_list):
    position_probabilities.extend([i[0]] * i[1])

for position, probability in zip(positions_list, probability_list):
    position_probabilities.extend([position] * probability )
```

Python 3.6 offers you the new [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function:

```
positions_list = ['QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'OL', 'DL', 'LB', 'DB', 'P', 'K']
probability_list = [5, 6, 10, 5, 15, 15, 12, 13, 2, 2]
position = random.choices(positions_list, probability_list, k=1)[0]
```

---

In `create_states_data` I think this would look a bit more readable (you could also use a dict comprehension here, but it'd look a bit dense):

```
for i in reader:
    states[i['state']] = {'abbreviation': i['abbreviation'],
                          'population': i['population'],
                          'towns': {}}
```

---

Regarding the **global variables** `first_names_list, last_names_list` etc., since you don't mutate them later, they are global **constants**. You can just access them in the `create_character` function and don't have to pass them. The convention is to use uppercase names for constants to signal to other programmers that they mustn't be changed, e.g. `FIRST_NAMES_LIST`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I actually made a mistake copying over the code. I do need `player_id_index` (unless you could recommend a better solution) because it allows me to create additional players later on, and keep track of how many I've made so far. I know global variables are a no-no. Are global constants acceptable?

Comment: @drewd423 Global constants are bad. I'll have to revert your edit, answer invalidation is a big no-no around Code Review.

Comment: @Mast Sorry about that. What's the best way to show the corrected code? Just add another block?

Comment: @Mast please explain why global constants are bad.

Comment: @skrx Wow, that was a mistake on my part. Globals are bad, but constants are the one exception to the rule. Provided they're uppercase like you mentioned so they don't get changed accidentally.